# Hadoop Input format

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

While preparing hadoop exam came across below question for which I could not understand correct answer, not sure about correctness about question.

Given a directory of files with the following structure: line number, tab character, string:

```
Example:

1. abialkjfjkaoasdfjksdlkjhqweroij
2. kadf jhuwqounahagtnbvaswslmnbfgy
3. kjfteiomndscxeqalkzhtopedkfslkj
```

You want to send each line as one record to your Mapper. Which InputFormat would you use to
complete the line: setInputFormat (________.class);

```
A. DBInputFormat
B. KeyValueTextInputFormat
C. SequenceFileInputFormat
D. SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat
```

Answer: C

But in opinion in order to achieve this either of `KeyValueTextInputFormat` or `SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not C or D. Because they require the input data to be sequence files which is not the case as far as I could understand